# How to subtract checkboxed values from a total

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column of values with the value sum at the top.
The column to the right of this column has checkboxes adjacent to each value (except sum). 
I would like to fix a formula I have to ensure the sum does not include all values that have their respective checkboxes checked.

I know this is wrong because it only includes one cell reference instead of all cells that are checked.

`=(SUM(S3:S43)-(IF(T3=TRUE,-S3)))`

This satisfies only T3, but not the entire column of values IF their adjacent checkboxes are checked.
What needs to be adjusted in the formula?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
= ArrayFormula
  (  
    SUM(S3:S43) - 
    IF
      ( t3:offset(t3,
        MAX(
             if
               ( isblank(S3:S43), 
                 0, 
                 row(S3:S43)
               )
            ) - ROW(S3), 0) = TRUE , - S3:S43
      )
  )
```